# Proxy Getting RangeError

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I am trying to intercept get and set operations using proxies. Setting works perfectly, but getting triggers "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in an infinite loop. I am trying to simply log during the interception and return the default behavior.

Working:

```js
testobject = {}
testobject = new Proxy(testobject, {
 set(target, property, value, receiver) {
  console.log("setting", target, property, value, receiver)
  return(Reflect.set(target, property, value, receiver))
 }
})
testobject.done = true
console.log(testobject.done)
```

Broken:

```js
testobject = {}
testobject = new Proxy(testobject, {
 get(target, property, receiver) {
  console.log("getting", target, property, receiver)
  return(Reflect.get(target, property, receiver))
 },
 set(target, property, value, receiver) {
  console.log("setting", target, property, value, receiver)
  return(Reflect.set(target, property, value, receiver))
 }
})
testobject.done = true
console.log(testobject.done)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the receiver paramters.

```js
testobject = {}
testobject = new Proxy(testobject, {
 get(target, property) {
  console.log("getting", target, property)
  return(Reflect.get(target, property))
 },
 set(target, property, value) {
  console.log("setting", target, property, value)
  return(Reflect.set(target, property, value))
 }
})
testobject.done = true
console.log(testobject.done)
```